# Написание ботов для сайтов с AJAX, с помощью Selenium или PhantomJS. Как отслеживать изменения, вносимые в DOM уже JSом (либо сами AJAX-запросы)?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, бот, сниффер

Свое изучение столь перспективного направления, как разработка ботов (автоматических клиентов) для всяких-разных сайтов/сервисов, я в свое время, как и любая школота, начал с браузерных движков (WebBrowser - Internet Explorer и Awesomium).

Первыми камнями преткновения стали:

1. столь популярный ныне AJAX, который на многих сайтах динамически подгружал некий контент, и это нельзя было толком отследить, а значит, и получить этот контент.
2. загрузка файлов в поля input type=file (через JS невозможно загрузить файл в такое поле, разве что методом тупого автокликинга, ну а каких-то особых средств для этого, движки не предоставляли (хотя теоретически вполне могли бы, мать их!))

Тогда я открыл для себя HTTP-сниффер (Fiddler - мой любимый), а затем и HTTP-запросы (надо сказать, запросы я открыл чуть ранее - работая с официальными API, вроде как у VK, но то знакомство было очень поверхностным, да и это уже совсем оффтоп, ибо мы говорим о тех сайтах, у которых подходящего API вообще нет).
Низкоуровневость этого подхода обеспечивает основные его плюсы (быстродействие, и универсальность - прокатывает для 99,99% всех сайтов), но она же и создает недостатки: трудоемкость и нестабильность-нестойкость к любым мерам по борьбе с ботами от админов.
Очень тяжело имитировать все заголовки, какие отправляет браузер (а иначе серверу очень легко бот отличить от браузера).

Порой сложно разобраться, какие точно отсниффенные запросы надо отправлять, а какие нет.
Также сложно иногда разобраться, как JS генерирует иные значения (и наладить алгоритм у себя).
И т.д.

В целом это приемлемо для многих случаев, поэтому отказываться от этого подхода я не собираюсь. Но каждой задаче - свой инструмент.
А есть задачи, где стабильность и быстрота написания - важнее быстродействия.
Возвращаться к простым браузерным движкам желания нет, потому к Selenium и PhantomJS сперва относился скептически.

Но очень подкупило то, что **PhantomJS, оказывается, содержит те самые "особые средства" для загрузки файлов в input type=file**, которые простые не-специальные движки (мать их!) не предоставляют!

И вот вопросы:

1. Загрузка файлов - ОК.
   **А можно ли с помощью PhantomJS также и отслеживать, перехватывать изменения в DOM-модели, которые вносит JS с AJAX-запросов?**
   Вроде там есть возможность перехватывать те запросы (пример кода в треде таки не помешает)))
   А если надо отловить именно изменения в DOM? Mutation Events там работают? А может и для этого есть "особые средства"?
2. **А как там дела у Selenium** в плане загрузки файлов, отслеживания HTTP-запросов, изменений в DOM?

Comment: VZVZ, мне кажется, если вы уберёте из текста всю «лирику» и чётко сформулируете **один** вопрос, то шансов на получение ответа станет значительно больше.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну, не сказать, чтобы я так уж горел желанием как можно быстрее получить хоть какой-то ответ на вопрос))) Я все же реверс-инженер, изучать неизучаемое - моя работа. У меня рано или поздно все изучается, хотите вы этого или нет. Просто хотелось поговорить с реальными спецами отрасли - а в их положении лирика не помешает. Зато им наверняка будет что сказать и по прочим пунктам, которые к теме напрямую не относятся. По себе знаю.

Comment: _"AJAX, который на многих сайтах динамически подгружал некий контент, и это нельзя было толком отследить"_ - можно. есть FiddleCore, другой вариант: добавить на страницу свой script с MutationObserver и перехватывать события.

Comment: "можно. есть FiddleCore" - теперь я в курсе, но во-первых он не бесплатный для любой коммерции (и стоит очень дорого), во-вторых, возможны проблемы с фаерволами и прочими системами защиты (это же лазейка для Adware и прочих зловредов), в-третьих, это просто неудобно и костыльно. Насчет MutationObserver, не надо забывать, что он числится как "deprecated" и вообще мало где поддерживается. Используя WebBrowser (который дергает IE непонятно какой версии) невозможно гарантировать поддержку подобных фич на любой машине. Другое дело Awesomium.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, PhantomJS(версии 2 и выше) имеет стандартный для браузеров MutationObserver, который собственно и позволяет перехватывать изменения в DOM. **PhantomJS** - это вполне себе полноценный [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), который рендерит страницы не на настоящий экран, а на "виртуальный экран" внутри его собственного процесса.
2. Всё хорошо с этим у Selenium - он позволяет делать всё это. **Selenium** - это набор API для манипуляции слегка модифицированными полноценными браузерами. Он может использовать практически все возможности, которые они предоставляют.

Comment: 1. Что именно "да"? 2. Я в курсе про то, что из себя представляют Selenium и PhantomJS. Но мне нужны не возможности браузерных движков (которые есть в оригинальных движках), а именно сверх этих возможностей, в частности то же самое взаимодействие с input type=file.

Comment: @VZVZ, Я отвечал на то, что вы спросили: PhantomJS(версии 2 и выше) имеет стандартный для браузеров MutationObserver, который собственно и позволяет перехватывать изменения в DOM; Всё хорошо у Selenium с загрузкой файлов, отслеживанием запросов и изменений в DOM - он позволяет делать всё это. Обновил ответ.